# Cassandra - DataSax PHP Driver - Timeout

Tags: php, cassandra

I'm having problems with timeout using the DataSax php driver for Cassandra.
Whenever I execute a certain command it always throws this exception after 10s:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Cassandra\Exception\TimeoutException' with message 'Request timed out'
```

My php code is like this:

```
$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()->build();
$session   = $cluster->connect("my_base");
$statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM my_table WHERE my_colunm = 1 AND my_colunm2 >= '2015-01-01' ALLOW FILTERING")
$result    = $session->execute($statement);
$row = $result->first();
```

My settings in **cassandra.yaml** is:

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 500000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 1000000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 50000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 1000000
```

I've already tried this:

```
$result    = $session->execute($statement,new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions([
        'timeout' => 120
    ])
);
```

and this:

```
$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()->withDefaultTimeout(120)->build();
```

and this:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

And it always throws the TimeoutException after 10s..
I'm using **Cassandra 3.6**
Any idea?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I've got same problem - timeout after 10s no matter what i change.

Answer (score 1):

Using `withConnectTimeout` (instead of, or together with `withDefaultTimeout`) might help avoid a `TimeoutException` (it did in my case)

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()->withConnectTimeout(60)->build();
```

However, if you need such a long timeout, then there is probably an underlying problem that will need solving eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you are doing wrong.

1. ALLOW FILTERING : Be careful. Executing this query with allow filtering might not be a good idea as it can use a lot of your computing resources. Don't use allow filtering in production Read the
   datastax doc about using ALLOW FILTERING
   https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?hl=allow,filter
2. count(*) : It also a terrible idea to use count(*). count(*) actually pages through all the data. So a select count(*) from userdetails without a limit would be expected to timeout with that many rows. Some details here: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/counting-key-in-cassandra/

How to Fix it ?

- Instead of using ALLOW FILTERING, You should create index table of
  your clustering column if you need query without partition key.
- Instead of using count(*) you should create a counter table